# After changing log schema, zeppelin demo Java app giving compile error & referring to old schema class

Tags: java, apache-zeppelin, kaa

In the Zeppelin demo, I changed the log schema to include some new fields. Used the same namespace as in the last log schema but used a new name as shown below:

[image]

Downloaded the new SDK. Placed it in lib directory of the demo app folder. Ran the mvn clean install command but it's giving a compile error as below.

> [ERROR]
>   /Users/anilsagar/Downloads/JZeppelinDataAnalyticsDemo/src/main/java/org/kaaproject/kaa/demo/zeppelin/SimulatorManager.java:[20,33]
>   cannot find symbol   symbol:   class PowerReport   location: package
>   org.kaaproject.kaa.sample

"PowerReport" is the name of the old log schema which I have replaced with a new name in the new log schema. Why is it still looking for the old schema name?

Comment: It seems that if one is defining a new application CT and using that in a log schema then the application sdk does not pick the right names in the source code generated. I thought automated SDK creation took care of this.

Comment: Are you sure that you remove the old class name from source file because it seems like you left source code of Zeppelin demo unchanged?